# How to block a wbsite using .htacces?

Tags: .htaccess

Today, I was interviewed for the post of webserver admin, and the interviewer asked one question that I never heard before..ever:

> using .htaccess file how to down a live website?

Any one know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you control the website, just put this in the .htaccess file in the root web directory:

```
deny from all
```

If you don't control the website, there is no way to do this unless there is a security vulnerability in the website unrelated to .htaccess.

Comment: Dude...i think deny from all entry is for different purpose..to allow certain ips..

Comment: See [here](http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html#3): it can be used to block certain files from certain ip's, or it can be used to block everything from everyone, which would effectively "down" the website.

Comment: simply i put this entry in .htaccess file in the root dir insie htdocs but its doesnot make any affect in site...still site is live? only